# Redirect after successfull login /or failed login

Tags: php, html, mysql

for my page I created a login. It works all as planned, but how do I make it redirect to another page automatically when the login was successfull and to a different page when it was not?

Different topic, I am new to this page, how do I make four spaces for the quote automatically? Putting four spaces manually in front of each line seems a bit weird.
Thanks for any help :)
Chris

```
    <?php session_start()?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>checklogin</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("mysql.freehostingnoads.net","u291_admin","...","u291_login");
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }



$sql= "SELECT * FROM login_data";
$result= mysqli_query ($con, $sql);
$row= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
if($row["username"] == $_POST["user"] && $row["password"] == $_POST["pwd"]){

    $_SESSION['username'] =$_POST["user"];


    echo "You succesfully logged in";
   echo '<br /> If you are not redirected automatically please click <a href="showdata.php">here</a>';
    //header("location:hidden.php");


}
else
{   echo "Wrong username or password";
    // header("location: www./index.html");
}



?>  

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For "four spaces", highlight anything that needs to be marked as code and hit the `{}` button in the editor.

Comment: If you have 1M users, would you select all of them for one wants to login? And if your user data is located deep in the table you try to match the first member's data. Use  `WHERE` condition in your SQL

Comment: First, change `<?php session_start()?>` to `<?php session_start(); ?>` missing semi-colon

Comment: Would you be able to move the echo messages to your other pages? Otherwise you could use javascript

Comment: Also for your query, you are only checking the first row returned, i dont think this will work. Use a WHERE clause to find a matching username and password. You should hash your password with a salt for a bit of security.

Answer (score 1):

You have already found

```
header("location:index.html");
```

But the problem is, your headers are already sent. You shouldn't echo anything before this.

Comment: Which will not work because OP's already performed output by outputting page headers and whatnot, but otherwise, yes, this is how it'd be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already output headers, then a javascript redirect could be a solution for you

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($row["username"] == $_POST["user"] && $row["password"] == $_POST["pwd"]){
    $_SESSION['username'] =$_POST["user"];
    header("location:showdata.php");   
}
else
{    
    header("location: index.html");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are able to use client-side meta tag of refresh:

```
<?php
     echo "You succesfully logged in";
     echo '<br /> If you are not redirected automatically please click <a href="showdata.php">here</a>';
?>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://someSite.com/hidden.php" />

<?php   
     }
     else{
          echo "Wrong username or password";
?>
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;URL=http://someSite.com/" />
<?php
     }        
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is rewrite your code w/ an MVC like laravel, then you could do something like

... UsersController ...

```
public function getLogin(){
    if(isset(_SESSION['username']){
        Redirect::back()->with('message', 'Login Successful');
    } else {
        Redirect::to('/')->with('message', 'Login failed');
    }
}
```

one benefit is all the db connection logic is taken care of inside Laravel's eloquent ORM, it's also got a lot of security measures, and a build in user auth system so you wouldn't actually use the Session data as such. There are other MVCs as well, and full-blown user login systems you could use like Sentry. If you're looking to build an application rapidly it may behoove you to pick an mvc.